# Wordpress - How can break dynamic content up into multiple divs

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a template page with separate modules, each with their own content that I would like to be able to edit in the WP text editor. So all of this content should be on one page but broken up into its separate parts. I have been using

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

to display the content but that displays all the content entered into the text editor box.

So basically, I'm asking how to break up the text entered into WP dynamically. Is there a way to tag a certain content block such as a paragraph or an image so that I can set where in the template it is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, my friend, are looking for [Custom Fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). You can implement them yourself with the meta box functions like [`add_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/), but then you're also looking at sanitizing and saving the data through your own functions.

You may be more comfortable using the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin. It has over a million downloads and handles all the relational, data-type, and storage for you.

You can, for instance, very easily insert an "Image Upload Field" only on "Posts" or on "Posts and Pages", and then use the [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) or [`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) function in your template:

```
<?php the_field( 'my_custom_image_field' ); ?>
```

You should be able to omit the `$post_id` parameter because it defaults to the current post id, similar to [`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) and [`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) functions.